# not CONCATENATE row if one cell is empty

Tags: excel, concatenation, string-concatenation

I have text data in A2, B2 and C2 cells. In this moment I set:

```
E2 =CONCATENATE(A2;B2;C2)
```

But how can I set E2 so to NOT CONCATENATE three of them at all - and leave E2 blank - if B2 is empty?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the most recent versions of Excel you can put the following formula inside E2 cell:

```
= IF(B2 <> "", CONCATENATE(A2, B2, C2), "")
```

while for my Excel 2007 this was the right one:

```
= IF(B2 <> ""; CONCATENATE(A2; B2; C2); "")
```

It means that if `B2` is not empty [`<>` means different, `""` means empty] then you `CONCATENATE`. Otherwise you leave it empty

The general syntax for newer versions is the following:

```
= IF(test, [if true], [if false])
```

while for the past ones:

```
= IF(test; [if true]; [if false])
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the TRIM function to remove any blank spaces? That way you can concatenate all of the fields without worrying if they're blank or not.

```
=CONCATENATE (TRIM(A2),TRIM(B2),TRIM(C2),TRIM(E2))
```

Comment: Thank you, but my point is that If the B2 is empty I dont want to CONCATENATE at all, but I want to keep that blank space visible. But TRIM function will work for me too, but in other case.